# Get all elements with a certain property

Tags: jquery, tooltip, element

I'm using jQuery, what would be the best way to get every element with a certain property?
I want to give some elements a 'tooltip' property so I can run some jQuery over it and make some special tooltips for specific elements.  How can this be done?

Comment: You will need to be more specific, what property would you be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute selector:

```
$("div[tooltip]")
```

EDIT: Other users have posted tooltip='tooltip' - that will select elements with a specific value for tooltip.  My suggestion will select any div with a tooltip attribute defined.

Answer (score 3):

You should do this with a css class.

```
<a class="tooltip">Tooltip 1</a>
<img class="tooltip" />
<div>No Tooltip</div>
<div class="tooltip">Tooltip</div>
```

Then you can just select them all with jQuery like:

```
$('.tooltip')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you HAVE to select by attribute, you can use something like this:

```
$("[tooltip='tooltip']");
```

or more suitably:

```
$("[tooltip]");
```

Although using a class makes a lot more sense, as PaulPRO stated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do:

```
 $("*[tooltip]")
```

this selects all elements. If you need only some elements you can also filter on the attribute:

```
 $("*[tooltip='somevalue']")
```